# AMC12B Problem, probability

Tags: probability, contest-math

> An unfair coin lands on heads with a probability of $\tfrac{1}{4}$. When tossed $n$ times, the probability of exactly two heads is the same as the probability of exactly three heads. What is the value of $n$ ?

$$P(\text{heads}) = \frac{1}{4}$$

Then $n$ times would be:

$$\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^n$$

But that isnt correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: By the binomial theorem:

$$Pr(\text{exactly two heads})=\binom{n}{2}(\frac{1}{4})^2(\frac{3}{4})^{n-2} = \binom{n}{3}(\frac{1}{4})^3(\frac{3}{4})^{n-3}=Pr(\text{exactly three heads})$$

Solve for $n$

> $$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}(\frac{1}{4})^2(\frac{3}{4})^{n-2}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}(\frac{1}{4})^3(\frac{3}{4})^{n-3}$$

.

> $$\frac{3}{8}=\frac{n-2}{24}$$

.

> $$n=11$$

---

There also exists another pair of solutions, given the convention that $\binom{n}{r}:=0$ whenever $n<r$, you have if you flip a total of 1 time, or a total of zero times, or some other impossible scenario, you will never flip exactly two heads, nor will you flip exactly three heads.  Hence $Pr(\text{exactly two heads})=0=Pr(\text{exactly three heads})$ works as well.  That is more than likely not the answer they were looking for.  To avoid this as an answer, the question should have stated "with $n$ and integer greater than or equal to 2".

Comment: how do you use the binomial theorem with probability? I've never seen this

Comment: The binomial theorem comes in two parts.  One for counting situations like $(x+y)^n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}x^iy^{n-i}$, and as an immediate corollary if you set $x=p$ and $y=(1-p)$ you get $1=(p-(1-p))^n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$.  Each term for the summands on the right is precisely the probability of getting *exactly* $i$ successes in $n$ trials.

Comment: Thank you! But how are the terms on the RHS probability of $i$ successes?

Comment: If you were to imagine a tree diagram, where ups denote success and downs denote failures,  you will see that there are precisely $\binom{n}{i}$ number of leaves with exactly $i$ successes.  The probability of reaching each of those leaves individually will be precisely $p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$ (although the order in which you multiply will vary depending on the order of successes to failures).  To reach *any* of the leaves will then be $\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$, hence the formula.